# Eclipse jar conflicted on project classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, classpath

I am using eclipse with the GWT SDK. Within my project I use Httpclient and within the GWT SDK they also use an older version of HttpClient which is missing a method I use. This causes a conflict in eclipse where my code will no longer build from within eclipse because the HttpClient jar from the GWT SDK overrides the one I provided for the project. This prevents the running the application on the eclipse tomcat server.

The question is, is there a way to override this behavior, the GWT SDK jars are not needed for the project they are only there to run the GWT tools.

- James

Answer (score 4):

One of the solutions is to change the order of the libraries in the **Eclipse Java build path** of your project.

By putting the jar containing the update version of `HttpClient` above `GWT` jar, you will have solved your problem.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this, but after a month of this issue it finally works.

Comment: @James Can you please tick my answer by pressing the tick next to my answer